# Having Api Cors Problems in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I am having a problem displaying data from an Api, I am getting this errors
 `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://swapi.py4e.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`and this one
`xhr.js:177 GET https://swapi.py4e.com/ net::ERR_FAILED` and this one `createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error at createError (createError.js:16) at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)`
Any help would be highy appriciated

```
import React,{useEffect, useState}from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';

function Home() {

    const [data, setData] =  useState([]);
    const apiURL = "https://swapi.py4e.com/";
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(apiURL)
        setData(response.data) 
    }
    return (
        <div >
          <button onClick={fetchData}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Home
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you can't just access an API without a specific API key. Every  browser natively implements a so-called [CORS-policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). What this does, basically, is that it doesn't allow a domain ("https://swapi.py4e.com/" in your case) to be accessed from a different domain or server ("localhost" in your case). This is a security measure.

Publicly accessible API's either generate an API key for you to use, or they allow access from any domain, therefore circumventing the CORS-policy. In both cases, however, the answer lies with the server on "https://swapi.py4e.com/". If you control that server, then you should allow access from you IP-address (or anywhere while developing) and then from the specific domain where your website is hosted (in production). If you don't control the server, then you would need an API key from the people controlling that server or you would have to ask them to grant your server access, by whitelisting your IP-address.